# ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to import keras in Vscode after downloading tensorflow and Keras using pip install tensorflow, and pip install keras, however it shows me the error of ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location), I have tried to upgrade tensorflow but its not working, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install tensorflow library

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and then use below import statement

```
from tensorflow import keras
```